# SQL Check (car rental)

Tags: mysql

Hey so im trying to add a check to my DB. I am currently creating a MySQL database for a car rental ( its a project for college ) and my constraint is that the person will only be an approved customer IF they have a driver number present so ...

```
CREATE TABLE  customers  (
   customer_id  int(50) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
   fname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   lname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   address  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   city  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   county  ENUM('Armagh','Carlow','Cavan','Clare','Cork','Derry','Donegal','Down','Dublin','Fermanagh','Galway','Kerry','Kildare','Kilkenny','Laois','Leitrim','Limerick','Longford','Louth','Mayo','Meath','Monaghan','Offaly','Roscommon','Sligo','Tipperary','Tyrone','Waterford','Westmeath','Wexford','Wicklow') NOT NULL,
   phone  int(10) NOT NULL,
   email  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   payment_method  ENUM ('Visa', 'Amex', 'Cash', 'American Express', 'Mastercard') NOT NULL,
   status  ENUM('Approved','Unapproved'),
   driver_no int(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The check be something like ... ?

CHECK driver_no PRESENT?

whats the command to see if something is present. They must have a driver number to rent a car.

Comment: You can format queries like this by indenting four spaces or selecting and using the `{}` button.

Comment: Using an `ENMUM` for a list of regions like this seems like a very bad idea. Adding a new county requires altering your schema, something that's often a painful operation. Instead create a proper relational table. The same goes for things like payment methods. Additionally try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like names and email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Comment: Your `int(10) NOT NULL` constraint will make sure it's not null (has a value assigned when saved/created) and that it's an integer. You could (should) use an `unsigned int(10)` since the number likely should not be negative. If you need more validity check than that, you'd do that in your db application when you create/save the record. Assuming you're using some kind of db library or active record framework, there are often events they support for that (like "on create" or "on save"). Note that the "10" here is just a display width. It does not enforce a range on the value.

Comment: thanks guys i still dont know how to do it what u mean tadman

Comment: What kind of "command" do you mean? Why not check for that condition in your code?

Comment: I have a driving licence. The 'number' written on it isn't an integer. Does that mean I cannot rent a car?

Comment: Nico - that my problem i dont know how to do that

Comment: strawberry - thanks

Comment: Ah, it's only for residents of Eire. I don't know what RoI numbers look like, but those in the north must be like UK ones (for the next few days anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;

CREATE TABLE customer
(customer_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,firstname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,licence_no VARCHAR(30) NULL
);

INSERT INTO customer VALUES
(1,'John',NULL),
(2,'Paul','LMW281F'),
(3,'George',NULL),
(4,'Ringo','STAR123');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rentals;

CREATE TABLE rentals
(rental_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,customer_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO rentals 
SELECT NULL, customer_id FROM customer WHERE firstname = 'John' AND licence_no IS NOT NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT * FROM rentals;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```